# Get Image back to its original location

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have the following HTML and JS.  When i click on the image the images zooms. This is working.  But then I zoom out I want to retract the image to the original location when It was loaded.

Consider image being dragged to right a little and then zoomed.

What I want is when its zoomed out its relocated to the original location when it was loaded.

What am I doing wrong?  I need the effect this page has [here](http://www.xflip.com/samples/e-magazine1/files/mobile/#1).  When you drag the image and release it, it will go to its original position.

**JS**

```
    var isZoom=1;
    var stage=new Kinetic.Stage({
                container:'container',
                width:700,
                height:700,
                id:'kineticstage',
                name:'kineticstage'
                });

    var layer=new Kinetic.Layer({});

    var group = new Kinetic.Group({
        width:700,
        height:700,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(group);   


    // set the images
    var pages = ["http://197.242.159.63/reader/demo/img/face.jpg"];

    var loadedPage = 0;
    function loadPage(pageno){
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            var kimage = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                image: imageObj,
                width:700,
                height:700
            });

            // add to layer
            group.add(kimage);
            stage.add(layer);
        };

        // load the page image
        imageObj.src = pages[pageno - 1];
    }

    // page 1
    loadPage(1);


    var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: group,
        duration: 1.0,
        rotation:0,
        scaleX: 1.5,
        scaleY: 1.5,
        easing:Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut
    });

    group.on('dblclick dbltap',function(e){
        if(isZoom == 1){
            tween.play();
        }
        else{
            tween.reverse();
        }
        layer.batchDraw();
        isZoom = (isZoom>0) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" > 
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" >
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"><!-- --></div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JkrsY/)

Comment: Not really seeing any zooming... where do you click?

Comment: @meewoK: double-click :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragging your kinetic group will cause its x,y to change.

To "undo" the drag, just reset the group back to its original x,y position:

In your case, you created the group at its default position of 0,0 so reset like this:

```
group.setX(0);
group.setY(0);
```